# Autocomplete textbox column in datagridview from SQL

Tags: c#, datagridview, autocomplete

I am trying to make a column which will suggest when I start typing in it and the data suggestions will be coming in a SQL table, I have tried using some codes here and in other sites but none seems to work properly to my needs.

Here is one of the codes that I have tried:

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn txt = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
 txt.Name = "Product Code";
 txt.Width = 250;
 dataGridView1.Columns.Add(txt); 

con.Open();
 try
 {
 cd = new SqlCommand();
 cd.Connection = con;
 cd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblmaster";
 da = new SqlDataAdapter();
 da.SelectCommand = cd;
 dt = new DataTable();
 in the data source.
 da.Fill(dt);


 foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
 {
 if (e.Control is TextBox)
 {
 DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl txt = e.Control as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;
 txt.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(r.Field&lt;string&gt;("Product Code"));
 txt.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
 txt.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
 }

 }

 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
 da.Dispose();
 con.Close();
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? & it would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: @JohnB sorry my bad, I have already edited it and included the code that I have tried

Comment: are you trying do achieve like a search function? when you type specific text in that cell it will suggest all data that can be match with that specific text?

Comment: yes, same as that

Comment: did you try the basic approach? like when `value change` of specific cell trigger, call your search query and insert the result data in other datagrid and display it.

Comment: It should be in the TextChanged Event if you want it while typing and then clear your datagridview and replace it by the data that matches the value of  what you're typing.